# Use grep to select certain words with special characters

Tags: sed, grep

I have a file that looks like this:

```
chr4    StringTie   exon    185054979   185055237   1000    +   .   gene_id `"MSTRG.41311"; transcript_id "ENST00000658673.1"; exon_number "2"; gene_name `"LINC02436"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000250754.6";
chr4    StringTie   exon    185069961   185070030   1000    +   .   gene_id `"MSTRG.41311"; transcript_id "ENST00000658673.1"; exon_number "3"; gene_name "LINC02436"; ref_gene_id "ENSG00000250754.6";
chr6    HAVANA  exon    169067764   169068299   .   +   .   gene_id "ENSG00000234519.2"; transcript_id "ENST00000666733.1"; exon_number "1"; gene_name "RP3-495K2.1";
```

I want to only keep the gene id information so the file will look like this:

```
MSTRG.41311
MSTRG.41311
ENSG00000234519.2
```

I have tried the following:

```
cat file.gtf|sed 's/!ENSG*//g'|sed 's/!ENSG*//g' > myfile.txt.
```

But this does not give me the desired output. I think this is because of the quotation marks which is a special character but I'm not sure.
Can someone help with this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also try do this with cut -d"*delimiter*" -f *columns nb*

For example :

```
cat file.gtf | cat f.txt | cut -d"\"" -f 1
```

The \ is use because " can't be place between two others " "

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (GNU sed):

```sh
sed -E 's/gene_id/\x0/;s/.*\x0 `?"([^"]+)".*/\1/' input
```

Since `gene_id` occurs twice on the first two lines (and you seem to be intereseted in the first occurrence on each line), I can't just go with `sed 's/.*gene_id…`, otherwise the `.*` will eat everything up to the before the *last* `gene_id` on the line.

Therefore, my approach is to pick the first `gene_id` on each line and change it in a `\x0` character, via `s/gene_id/\x0/` (since there's no greedy `.*` before `gene_id`, it will match the first on the line).

Once I've marked that position with `\x0`, I can use it to "anchor" the rest of the regex in the following `s`ubstitution, where `.*\x0` will match everything on each line up to and including (what was) the first `gene_id` on the line, and `` `?"([^"]+)".* `` matches the rest of the line while capturing with `(…)` the part between `"`s.

---

I've used `-E` for extended regex, so I can use `(…)` instead of `\(…\)`, for instance.

Oh, the `` `? `` is just because you've put those backticks in the first two lines, so with `?` (which'd be `\?` without the `-E` option) I required that zero or one backtick matches at that position. Not sure if it was a copy and paste mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En 's/.*\<gene_id\>[^"]*"([^"]*)".*/\1/p' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E` and off implicit printing `-n` as this is a filtering operation.

Match the word `gene_id`, make a back reference to the string between the next pair of double quotes and replace the whole line by the back reference printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

Fast:

```
awk -v RS='[^[:alnum:]_.]+' 'f==1{print;f=0} $0=="gene_id"{f=1}'
```

100% POSIX:

```
awk -F '[^[:alnum:]_.]+' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i=="gene_id") {print $(i+1); next}}}'
```

Setting RS to a regular expression is not posix, but is commonly available.
You could adapt either to print any field, anywhere in the line.